# Spivak Calculus on Manifolds, problem 1-2

Tags: calculus, manifolds

I am confused about the *hint* Spivak adds to problem 1-2 in his Calculus on Manifolds:

> When does equality hold in Theorem 1-1(3)? *Hint:* Re-examine the proof;
>   the answer is not “when $x$ and $y$ are linearly dependent.”

The said (in)equality here would be:
$$
\left \lvert x + y \right \rvert \leq \left \lvert x \right \rvert + \left \lvert y \right \rvert 
$$

**My question:** Why is $x$ and $y$ being linear not the condition for equality?

If one squares both sides of the equation, one obtains for the LHS:
$$
\left \lvert x + y \right \rvert^2 = \left \lvert x \right \rvert^2 + \left \lvert y \right \rvert^2 + 2\sum^n_{i=1} x_i y_i \text{,}
$$
and for the RHS
$$
\left( \left\lvert x \right\rvert + \left\lvert y \right\rvert \right)^2 = \left \lvert x \right \rvert^2 + \left \lvert y \right \rvert^2 + 2 \left\lvert x \right\rvert \cdot \left\lvert y \right\rvert\text{.}
$$

Clearly, the LHS and RHS are equal if:
$$
\sum^n_{i=1} x_i y_i = \left\lvert x \right\rvert \cdot \left\lvert y \right\rvert \text{,}
$$

which is the case iff $x$ and $y$ are linearly dependent (as per Theorem 1-1(2)). What am I missing? Why is the answer not “when $x$ and $y$ are linearly dependent”? What other condition is there?

Comment: You need to note there's an absolute value in theorem 1-1(2).

Comment: Yeah, I managed to ignore the absolute value sign after staring at this the entire day.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If equality holds, as you say, they are linearly dependent. But the converse doesn't hold. Think of $x=(1,1)$ and $y=(-2,-2)=-2x.$

Suppose $y=\lambda x.$ Then

$$\lambda \sum_{i=1}^n\sum^n_{i=1} x_i^2= \left\lvert x \right\rvert \cdot \left\lvert y \right\rvert= |\lambda||x|^2.$$

What sign has to have $\lambda?$